# How do I configure VirtualBox to launch a VM from an external drive?

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

What steps do I need to take in order to use VirtualBox to access a CentOS 7 installation that is on a detached hard drive?

Here is the situation:

1. CentOS 7 and Windows 7 were installed on a PC in a dual boot fashion.
2. The dual boot PC died.
3. I extracted the hard drive and connected it to a new Windows 8.1 PC using an [Apricorn SATA Wire 3.0](https://www.apricorn.com/media/uploads/Apricorn_SATAWire3_Datasheet.pdf).
4. I installed VirtualBox on the new Windows 8.1 machine and created a new CentOS 7 VM.
5. I then started to create another VM called **CentOS old**, to access the contents of the detached hard drive from the old PC through the SATA Wire.  But I have not configured or tried to launch the **CentOS old** VM.  This posting asks how.

**How do I configure all the settings for the `CentOS old` VM so that I can successfully access all the contents from the CentOS portion of the old dead PC via VirtualBox?**

Here is a screenshot of the settings definition GUI for the desired VM in VirtualBox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, use the following `VBoxManage` command to get VirtualBox to boot from an external USB.

```
cd %programfiles%\oracle\virtualbox

VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "%USERPROFILE%"\desktop\usb.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive#
```

Where `#` is the disk drive **number** of the USB. Which can be found in Disk Manager (`diskmgmt.msc`) The code also uses Environmental Variables that should run without changing anything (except the `#`)

From there you can run a `dd` command, Windows program or utility in order to clone the CentOS drive. This will allow you to have a "physical" copy of the virtual image that you can boot from without needing the external USB plugged in.

Source: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/

Comment: Your using the drive **letter** when you need to use the drive **number**. DiskManagement >> Find Drive Letter `I` >> Drive **number** will be to the left. http://s9.postimg.org/rumejc47z/Untitled.png I recommend deleting your added edit, since both my directions and the source specifically mention drive number. Mostly importantly though, just because it's extra, unnecessary info.

Comment: Create a Virtual Machine like you normally would. Assigning RAM, you **don't** need to create a VHDD since you just did. You add the `.vmdk` file to the SATA controller where you have `CentOS Old.vdi` mounted in the image you posted. in case you need me to hold your hand >> http://s11.postimg.org/7kj8x33sj/Untitled2.png. If you prefer a `VDI, VHD, RAW` extension rather than the `VMDK` >> https://github.com/BiTinerary/ConVertual. I would like to add that upvotes are for accuracy/details of the question or answer. Not if you can get them to work or not, that's what the "mark as answered" is for.

Comment: Run VirtualBox as administrator and make sure you have ownership of the generated `.vmdk` >> Take ownership made easy: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Comment: I'm done. The `.vmdk` file you created was a **VIRTUAL** bootloader, you can't actually add/edit/save files. In order to do **that**, also mentioned in my answer post that you didn't pay attention to, you need to clone the drive using a `dd` command, or boot to a cloning tool and clone the virtual drive. Over and out.